# Using attention in a CNN attention model

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, attention-model

I am very new to python and ML.
I have a working CNN LSTM model as below:

```
def model_demo():
    inp = Input(shape=(6000,3), name='input')
    e = Conv1D(16, 9 , strides =1,  padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inp)
    e = BatchNormalization()(e) 
    e = Activation('relu')(e)
    
    e = Dropout(dropout_rate_cnn)(e)

    
    e = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, unroll=True)(e)
    e = Dropout(0.7)(UNIlstm)  
    e = BatchNormalization()(UNIlstm)

    
    e = TimeDistributed(Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01), activation='relu'))(e)
    e = BatchNormalization()(e)
    e = Dropout(0.7)(e)

    e = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01), activation='sigmoid'))(e)


    out_model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=e) #e.shape(6000,1)
```

I want to add attention to it that is provided by [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention). I am unsure about the inputs of this attention layer and whether to have a CNN LSTM Attention model or replace LSTM with Attention.

I tried to add Attnetion after the LSTM layer with the input as [e[0],e[1]] but this contributes 0 parameters to the model and has a model summary as (not sure if this is the right way):

```
tf.__operators__.getitem (Slic  (6000, 32)          0           ['lstm[0][0]']                   
 ingOpLambda)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem_1 (Sl  (6000, 32)          0           ['lstm[0][0]']                   
 icingOpLambda)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 attention (Attention)          (6000, 32)           0           ['tf.__operators__.getitem[0][0]'
                                                                 , 'tf.__operators__.getitem_1[0][
                                                                 0]']                             
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)            (6000, 32)           0           ['attention[0][0]']
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments have been rightly given in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/attention/) as you have quoted.

In general, either one of attention mechanism and LSTM will be used with CNN however I haven't found any information on using both of them together.

Attention mechanism has better performance than LSTM and hence you can replace LSTM with the former one.

Here is the code from the Keras official documentation on using CNN+Attention :-

```
# Variable-length int sequences.
query_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
value_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')

# Embedding lookup.
token_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=64)
# Query embeddings of shape [batch_size, Tq, dimension].
query_embeddings = token_embedding(query_input)
# Value embeddings of shape [batch_size, Tv, dimension].
value_embeddings = token_embedding(value_input)

# CNN layer.
cnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    filters=100,
    kernel_size=4,
    # Use 'same' padding so outputs have the same shape as inputs.
    padding='same')
# Query encoding of shape [batch_size, Tq, filters].
query_seq_encoding = cnn_layer(query_embeddings)
# Value encoding of shape [batch_size, Tv, filters].
value_seq_encoding = cnn_layer(value_embeddings)

# Query-value attention of shape [batch_size, Tq, filters].
query_value_attention_seq = tf.keras.layers.Attention()(
    [query_seq_encoding, value_seq_encoding])

# Reduce over the sequence axis to produce encodings of shape
# [batch_size, filters].
query_encoding = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(
    query_seq_encoding)
query_value_attention = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(
    query_value_attention_seq)

# Concatenate query and document encodings to produce a DNN input layer.
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(
    [query_encoding, query_value_attention])

# Add DNN layers, and create Model.
# ...
```